# custom validator in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a custom validator in my asp.net mvc3 application like this:

```
{
  if (customerToValidate.FirstName == customerToValidate.LastName)
            return new ValidationResult("First Name and Last Name can not be same.");

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public static ValidationResult ValidateFirstName(string firstName, ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (firstName == "Nadeem")
        {
            return new ValidationResult("First Name can not be Nadeem", new List<string> { "FirstName" });
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

and I have decorated my model like this:

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(CustomerValidator), "ValidateCustomer")]
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(CustomerValidator), "ValidateFirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

my view is like this:

```
@model CustomvalidatorSample.Models.Customer
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
    </div>
}
```

But validation doesn't fire. Please suggest solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know the validation doesn't fire? Are you setting a break point in your controller?

You are not displaying any validation errors in your view. You need to add the following lines to the view.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
```

You will want to remove the custom validation from the class.  Leave it on the properties though.